# Import & export XML file to Excel

Tags: xml

I am trying to import an xml file to edit some parameter and then export it back without changing the original structure.

to import it use the following macro Sub ImportXMLtoList() , to export the file i tryied all the code available on the net. but The resulting .xml file is with a structure completely different from the original file.

I have available the .biz and .xsd schema file but i am not able to use them to mantain the structure. I would like to do all using macro

All the file are available here: http://dropcanvas.com/4dy4l

Thanks for the support. Really appreciated

```
Sub ImportXMLtoList()
'Dim strTargetFile As String
Dim wb As Workbook


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'strTargetFile = "C:\example.xml"

strTargetFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("RICETTA (*.xml), *.xml")

If strTargetFile = False Then
MsgBox "Select a file!"

GoTo Fine
End If


Set wb = Workbooks.OpenXML(Filename:=strTargetFile, LoadOption:=xlXmlLoadList)
Application.DisplayAlerts = True


wb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("foglio2").Range("A1")
wb.Close False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


Fine:
End Sub
```